# VS Code not defining _WIN32

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

I have exactly the opposite problem to [VSCode turn of _WIN32 define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64440620/vscode-turn-of-win32-define) - Visual Studio Code is failing to define `_WIN32` for me. This is in a cross-platform project that is being developed on Windows with the Microsoft compiler, but needs to also be able to compile on Linux, so I have

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
```

failing, and VS Code then marks all references to Windows API types etc. with red underlines. (The include mechanism itself is working fine, e.g. it has no problem including regular C++ headers.)

Is there any known reason why VS Code on Windows might fail to define `_WIN32`? The question I linked suggests it should, and I haven't knowingly changed any settings related to it.

Comment: VSC does not define any variable. You have to add that to the `windows` specific part of the build task, or define it as an environment variable (`OS_SYSTEM`) and use that as argument on the build line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the problem is VSCode is using the wrong C++ compiler to gather the predefined macros, and that compiler does not predefine `_WIN32`.

To check, in Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), run "C/C++: Log Diagnostics". The output will show you which compiler VSCode found and what it detected as its built-in include path and preprocessor defines.  If my guess is correct, the diagnostics will show the wrong compiler being used, and `_WIN32` missing.

Assuming so, to solve this, use the command Palette to run "C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)", then set "Compiler path" to point at your compiler executable (`cl.exe` in this case).  That should solve the problem because VSCode will then query that compiler to determine the predefined macros, which will include `_WIN32`.  Re-run the diagnostics to confirm.

(I just gave a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66170310/2659307) to the question linked to in the question above, as I think both questions have essentially the same problem and solution, just with different details.)

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+P doesn't list anything like "C/C++: Log Diagnostics". It does list "C/C++: Edit Configurations (UI)" and when I go into that, it confirms it is indeed already pointing at the correct compiler... But when I exit that and look back at the code *without having changed anything*, it's now working correctly! So it must've been some kind of temporary glitch, but I will remember the edit configurations option in case of future need. Thanks!

Comment: After hitting Ctrl+Shift+P, type "diag" into the search box.  Do you still not see that command?  If so, what version of VSCode and the C/C++ extension are you using?

Comment: Yes, that does find it.