# Using windows library with CMake throws "undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport)"

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm migrating an existing application from Linux to Windows. I'm not a very experienced windows developer so I'm trying to stick to known tools. I'm using CLion and CMake to try to get this running.

The application calls to a blackbox library I have no knowledge of, just a zip file with .h, .dll and .lib files. The lInux counterpart includes .so and .h files I had no problem integrating.

The example code structure is as follows:

```
test/
├─ sdk/
│  ├─ include/
│  │  ├─ netsdk.h
│  ├─ lib/
│  │  ├─ kdnetsdk.dll
│  │  ├─ kdnetsdk.lib
├─ CMakeLists.txt
├─ main.cpp
```

main.cpp tries to call a function of this library:

```
#include "netsdk.h"

int main()
{
    int ret = NET_Init();
    return ret;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(test main.cpp)

add_library(sdk SHARED IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET sdk PROPERTY
        IMPORTED_LOCATION "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sdk/lib/kdnetsdk.dll")
set_property(TARGET sdk PROPERTY
        IMPORTED_IMPLIB "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sdk/lib/kdnetsdk.lib")
set_property(TARGET sdk PROPERTY
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:sdk/include>)

target_include_directories(test PUBLIC
        "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sdk/include"
)

target_link_libraries(test PRIVATE sdk)
```

When compiling this is the erroring output:

```
[2/2] Linking CXX executable test.exe
FAILED: test.exe 
cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Users\glamd\AppData\Local\Programs\CLion Nova\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\test.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100226~1.0\x64\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100226~1.0\x64\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin\lld-link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\test.dir\main.cpp.obj  /out:test.exe /implib:test.lib /pdb:test.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  D:\test\sdk\lib\kdnetsdk.lib  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\Llvm\x64\bin\lld-link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\test.dir\main.cpp.obj /out:test.exe /implib:test.lib /pdb:test.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console D:\test\sdk\lib\kdnetsdk.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\test.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\test.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1) with the following output:
lld-link: error: undefined symbol: __declspec(dllimport) NET_Init
>>> referenced by D:\test\main.cpp:6
>>>               CMakeFiles\test.dir\main.cpp.obj:(main)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

netsdk.h has thousands of lines, but these bits seem important:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

...

#ifdef WIN32
    #ifdef _NETSDK_
        #define NVR_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define NVR_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
    #define STDCALL _stdcall
#else
    #define NVR_API
    #define STDCALL
#endif

...

NVR_API s32 STDCALL NET_Init();
```

For some reason it seems the Linker can't find the function, I've been trying to configure CLion toolchain to use mingw or visual studio and every linker gioves the same error. Do I need a specific windows configuration? as I said, in linux I just pointed cmake to the .so and .h files without problems.

Comment: Does `kdnetsdk.lib` actually contain that symbol?

Comment: What *is* undefined is the symbol `NET_Init`. The `declspec` is just a decoration.

Comment: dumpbin /exports show the symbol in both .lib and .dll:

 _NET_Init@0

I Expect the library to be OK but it was provided by a thrid party

Comment: You seem to have `STDCALL` mismatch: `@0` suffix at `_NET_Init@0` seems to be `_stdcall` marker. DLL contains `_NET_Init@0`, but you link to raw `NET_Init`. You should add `target_compile_definitions(sdk INTERFACE _NETSDK_)`. (https://godbolt.org/z/x3EYd5fdK)

Comment: @R2RT `#define _NETSDK_` will cause the symbol to be marked `dllexport` which isn't correct

Comment: Whoops, that's right. So maybe `WIN32` is somehow missing?

Comment: @R2RT could be, `_WIN32` is the better define to use as it's defined by the compiler https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080233/where-is-win32-defined-and-how-can-i-include-this-definition-in-my-project

Comment: I've tried adding `target_compile_definitions(sdk INTERFACE _NETSDK_)` and WIN32 with and without underscores, also added ``#define _WIN32` with and  without underscore.

Seems the define are already somewhere as I'm getting 
```warning: '_WIN32' macro redefined [-Wmacro-redefined]
#define _WIN32
        ^
<built-in>(395,9): note: previous definition is here``` same thing when no underscore present.

I shouldn't need to understand the compiler and function signatures for a simple third party library to work, is this because the vendor missed something in the library?

Comment: They should be using `_WIN32`, `WIN32` is defined in a Windows header somewhere, so whether it's defined or not depends on your include order

Answer (score 0):

Stupidly easy solution... Looks like the library is x86 only, configured the CLion toolchain to x86 instead of amd64 and it started working. The CmakeLists.txt file is unchanged since my question post so it can be helpful for others.